# Unable to hit server with soap

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest

```
error = Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9205a02aa0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}}
```

I am getting this error when i am hitting the server.

```
NSString *strurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/WebInterface/upApp_anmai.aspx?validateXml=%@", [UserInfo sharedInstance].IP, AESvalidateXml];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strurl]];

request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = ***;
```

But if like this

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://181.125.78.237:81/ANMAIjz/WebInterface/upApp_anmai.aspx?validateXml=aEIakcuDeemSjpC5S/hr7+w+CDFLLfpEnZXZwYqAQx9a/NZsP6A4zYhgXX/ynAskPNLVgzuzt1iHgECXLyXCvsfj+c7WT6W7tLnuF050jBk4Yx2+Sk29GmjvzeYSGzrAirxZok3v//gwDU/VBORoxkc6LhlWHVb3c42clXixJB+GkJr2nRZpJgs48U4n1fVd"]];
```

it will be ok

Please any one advice me with this issue.

@thanks in advance

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", strurl);` And check whether the url is correct or not.

Comment: Unless your ip string contains ANMAIjz.